# HTML/CSS table column width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a table according to the following requirements and getting nowhere:

- the width of some columns must shrink to fit contents.
- the width on other columns must divide up remaining available width among themselves.
- table width must fill, but not exceed, parent width.

I came up with one approach ... set the shrinking columns width to 1px. That seemed to do the trick until the content of the expanding columns grows and ends up increasing the width of the table to exceed the width of it's parent, which violates the last requirement listed.

Any ideas? I'm broke.

I'm using Compass/Sass hyphenation, which helps with the last requirement (table does not exceed parent width). Works in Chrome perfectly. In Firefox, the table width is just a little too far. This is what my styles look like:

```
td.id
td.actions {
    text-align: right;

    /* trick table cells into fitting their content with nowrap and zero width */
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1px;
}

td {
    @include hyphenation;
}
```

Comment: What should happen if the remaining available space is negative?

Comment: What does that `@include hyphenation` thingy compile to?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using pixel widths instead of percentages. If you are, try "60%" or another appropriate value. Can you post your code?

Comment: Neither px or percent is an appropriate value for what I am trying to do. I want some columns to shrink to fit content, and the rest to expand to fill space. I don't want an arbitrary width value on any of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
td.actions {
table-layout:auto;
}
```

Comment: This will ignore the content, but "the width of some columns must shrink to fit contents".